# Is there a way to open the Console window on Node.js tools for Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, node.js, visual-studio, ntvs

I just downloaded the [Node.js tools for Visual Studio](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/releases/view/612573) and I can't find a way to open a Console window from inside VS.

It's useful to trigger `npm` commands like `install`, `run build`...

I know I could do it from the outside but I miss how easy it is in WebStorm, for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run npm from the interactive node.js window using the `.npm` command.

Or you can right-click on the node.js project and chose "Open Command Prompt Here" to open a console window to run npm.

Or you can right click on the npm node in the project and use the gui tool for managing packages.

The NTVS team has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaOnGN6byeo) where they talk about the npm support:

And there's also a [page on the npm support](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Npm) in the NTVS documentation.